# Pandas interpolate with new time scale

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, interpolation

I have a time series with timestamps recorded any time an event occurs (so no given frequency). The precision of the timestamp being the millisecond.
As this goes on for several thousands of lines and with many variables, I would like to create a new time range with a given frequency (here '5ms') and interpolate values at those time. So I tried this:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({"Time":pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-23 00:00:00.001',
'2016-01-23 00:00:00.013','2016-01-23 00:00:00.018',
'2016-01-23 00:00:00.024']),
"Value": [1,2,3,4]})

a = a.set_index(a["Time"])
b = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-23 00:00:00.00',
  end='2016-01-23 00:00:00.025', freq='5ms')
c = a.reindex(b).interpolate(method="time")
>>                        Time  Value
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.000  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.005  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.010  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.015  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.020  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.025  NaT    NaN
d=a.resample('5ms').interpolate()
>>                        Time  Value                             
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.000  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.005  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.010  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.015  NaT    NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.020  NaT    NaN
```

I guess that none of these solutions could work if the new time scale does not include the previous timestamps in it? I ended up going around this problem as follows:

```
e = a.reindex(a.index.union(b)).interpolate(method='time').reindex(b)
>>                        Time     Value
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.000  NaT       NaN
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.005  NaT  1.333333
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.010  NaT  1.749995
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.015  NaT  2.400031
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.020  NaT  3.333348
  2016-01-23 00:00:00.025  NaT  4.000000
```

But this looks heavy and not efficient to me. I would have expected that to be possible directly with the interpolation function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use resample, if you set the time on the index.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"Time":pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-23 00:00:00.001',
   '2016-01-23 00:00:00.013','2016-01-23 00:00:00.018',
   '2016-01-23 00:00:00.024']),
   "Value": [1,2,3,4]})

a.set_index('Time', inplace=True)    

print(a.resample('1ms').interpolate().resample('5ms').first())
```

output:

```
                        Value
Time                             
2016-01-23 00:00:00.000  1.000000
2016-01-23 00:00:00.005  1.333333
2016-01-23 00:00:00.010  1.750000
2016-01-23 00:00:00.015  2.400000
2016-01-23 00:00:00.020  3.333333
```

Still a bit workaround-ish. But it's something!

Resampling to 5 microseconds straight away gives a more coarse interpolation:

```
print(a.resample('5ms').first().interpolate())

                         Value
Time                          
2016-01-23 00:00:00.000    1.0
2016-01-23 00:00:00.005    1.5
2016-01-23 00:00:00.010    2.0
2016-01-23 00:00:00.015    3.0
2016-01-23 00:00:00.020    4.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does work but looks indeed as workaround-ish as my solution. I was wondering if it would be possible to directly interpolate on a new time index, without having to reindex or resample twice in a row. On my case study I have several thousands of lines and some variables I want to interpolate linearly, some I just want to 'ffill', other I just want the nearest value. Having to do this 2-reindexing + filling operation for all these cases takes a very long time to compute!

Comment: you can interpolate once directly using:
a.resample('5ms').interpolate() but the results were a really rough interpolation.

Comment: Are you refering to something else than what I called variable "d" in my example? It did not work here.

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work for you. For me it gives an answer. I'll post it under the other output.

Comment: thanks. FYI, I am running Pandas 0.19.1. I am still getting NaN running your code

Comment: I see what you mean, just updated from 18 to 19. Weird stuff. Will try to get it working a bit :)

Comment: I get it working using:
a.resample('5ms').first().interpolate()
Edited the answer.